# react-router 4 and redirecting programmatically

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect a user to where he came from, when going to a Login component. For now, actually, I'd be happy just to redirect to a known url. In this case, '/dashboard'.

My application starts with an app.js and the routes are defined as:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <div>
                    <Navbar />
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Home}  />
                        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                        <Route path='/contact' component={Contact} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/register" component={Register} /> 
                        <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route path="/accounts" component={AccountList} />
                        <Route path="/account" component={Account}/>
                    </div>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

I have navigated to Login, and the user has entered their credentials. I have validated against a WebAPI call, and have a success.. So I want to redirect.

I am doing this:

```
message = "Welcome, " + Auth.Auth.firstname();
history.push("/dashboard");
```

My imports for my login screen has:

```
import history from '../../helpers/history.js';
```

Where history.js is simply:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createHashHistory'
export default createHistory();
```

The push is executed, but the screen doesn't refresh. The URL simply updates to:

> http://localhost:8080/login#/dashboard

If I click my 'Dashboard' nav button, the URL changes to:

> http://localhost:8080/dashboard

and my screen loads the dashboard.

How should I be redirecting, problematically, when I need to?

Comment: Why you use `createHashHistory` ? And not `import { createHistory } from 'history'`

Comment: I'm not sure. I was trying to follow someones instruction, but this doesn't seem to work. Should I change the history.js file to use history/createHistory ?

Comment: createHashHistory is for managing urls using the `#` as in your example `http://localhost:8080/login#/dashboard` and createHistory for regular urls like `http://localhost:8080/dashboard`

Comment: When I change my history.js to use createHistory (Remove 'hash'), I get "_history.createHistory) is not a function".

Comment: @Craig I think you need to use: `this.props.history.push('/dashboard');`. I also don't believe you need to import history at all, as you should get access to it for free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to warp up your component `withRouter` then use`this.props.history.push('/dashboard')`

> no need to import history from '../../helpers/history.js';

Read more about [withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md)

> You can get access to the history object's properties and the closest
>   's match via the `withRouter` higher-order component.
>   `withRouter` will pass updated match, location, and history props to
>   the wrapped component whenever it renders.

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class AppA extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.props.history.push("/b");
    },1000)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1> Component A will redirect after 1 sec </h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default withRouter(AppA);
```

[image: Edit kk8pj61y0o]

Comment: You don't need to import `withRouter` and can `export default AppA;` If you modify your CodeSandbox code, removing `withRouter`, you'lll see it works the exact same way.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Yes but if the app doesn't have an instance of Router in its props which is giving `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.`

Comment: Thanks guys. This worked perfectly. Should I be using withRouter?

Comment: @Craig I prefer you to use `withRouter` to avoid any future troubles.